# PowerShell cmdlet Test-NetConnection not available

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012

I noticed that the cmdlet `Test-NetConnection` was not installed on Server 2012. Since Server 2012 comes with PowerShell version 3 so I thought it might help to update to the latest version 5.1.

I did the update but the cmdlet `Test-NetConnection` is still not available.

Only `Test-Connection` is present, but I need `Test-NetConnection` to test ports.

How can I get `Test-NetConnection` now?

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14409.1005
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14409.1005
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.34209
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1


PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Command Test-NetConnection
Get-Command : The term 'Test-NetConnection' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Command Test-NetConnection
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Test-NetConnection:String) [Get-Command], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCommandCommand
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The availability of many cmdlets is tied to the Windows version, not the PowerShell version. If you can't upgrade your Windows version you can't have `Test-NetConnection`.

You could use a commandline port scanner like [nmap](https://nmap.org/download.html) or [scanline](https://www.mcafee.com/ca/downloads/free-tools/scanline.aspx) for port tests, or you could connect to the port(s) yourself:

```
function Test-Port($server, $port) {
    $client = New-Object Net.Sockets.TcpClient
    try {
        $client.Connect($server, $port)
        $true
    } catch {
        $false
    } finally {
        $client.Dispose()
    }
}
```

Comment: too bad. I have to stick with it for now. I find this cmdlet very convenient as no extra install is required. I very much appreciate yor function, works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: is seems that the function send a SYN packet and do not wait for the ACK. So it is not as reliable as Test-NetConnection.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ipaddress = "serverName"
$port = "portNum"
$connection = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($ipaddress, $port)
if ($connection.Connected) {
     Write-Host "Success" 
} else { 
     Write-Host "Failed" 
}
```